# Generate random text from JSON file when button is pressed - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I want to create random text generator from json file which are called by button.
At this moment I have random text generator, but to refresh that I need to go back on another view and open same view.

How can I make it refresh by button?
I have tried creating this by function, but every time I was getting lot of errors...

ContentView code (except hacking swift code that allows me to run this code)

```
struct Quote: Codable {
        
        var text: String
        var author: String
        
        var shareMessage: String {
            return "\"\(text)\" - \(author)"
        }
    }
        
        struct PytaniaNormalne : View {
            @State private var quote : Quote?
            var body: some View {
                VStack {
                    if let quote = quote {
                        VStack {
                            VStack {
                                Text(quote.text)
                                    .font(.system(.title3))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                Text(quote.author)
                                    .font(.system(.title3))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                        }.frame(width: 240)
                            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7.0).fill(Color.blue))
                    }
                }.onAppear {
                    let quotes = Bundle.main.decode([Quote].self, from: "quotes.json")
                    quote = quotes.randomElement()
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

JSON FILE

```
[
    {
        "text": "Pytanie 1",
        "author": "tekst"
    },
    {
        "text": "Pytanie 2",
        "author": "tekst"
    },
    {
        "text": "Pytanie 3",
        "author": "teskt"
    },
    {
        "text": "Pytanie 4",
        "author": "tekst"
    },
    {
        "text": "Pytanie 5",
        "author": "author"
    },
    {
        "text": "Pytanie 6",
        "author": "author"
    },
    {
        "text": "Pytanie 7",
        "author": "author"
    }
]
```

Comment: "I have tried creating this by function, but every time I was getting lot of errors..." Can you show your attempt? You likely know how to make a `Button`, and all that needs to go in the action are your two lines `let quotes = ...` and `quote = `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, I've added the button below the `author` `Text`. Every time you tap it, `setRandomQuote` will be invoked, setting a random quote to your `@State` var, which subsequently will reload the view.

```
struct PytaniaNormalne : View {
    @State private var quote : Quote?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let quote = quote {
                VStack {
                    VStack {
                        Text(quote.text)
                            .font(.system(.title3))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text(quote.author)
                            .font(.system(.title3))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        
                        Button(action: setRandomQuote) {
                            Text("Refresh")
                                .font(.system(.title3))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding()
                                .background {
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                }
                        }

                    }
                }.frame(width: 240)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7.0).fill(Color.blue))
            } else {
                Text("click the button")
                   .font(.system(.title3))
                   .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func setRandomQuote() {
        let quotes = Bundle.main.decode([Quote].self, from: "quotes.json")
        quote = quotes.randomElement()
    }
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly. Big thanks! I tried do exactly the same, but didn't add 'private' before func. I am a newbie and still don't understand some basics. Thanks for your help

Comment: The `private` keyword doesn’t affect the outcome of this program, just the access level of the function. That means, that if you do mark it as `private`, then the `struct` that has it and that `struct` only, can see and use it.

Comment: hi, I've got a question. It is possible to make the "welcome text" when entering to this view? Now when user enter in this View it is showing random text. I want to make the welcome text for example "click the button".

Comment: I added an `else` to my answer. This is how it works; as long as the `quote` property is `nil`, the `else` statement will be activated. I also removed the `onAppear` modifier, in order to have no `quote`, until you press the button.

Comment: It's not working :( it shows me just blank screen - if I delete foreground color .white then its just a text